# Why does curl succeed from the command line but fail in this script?

Tags: curl, cygwin

i use Cygwin to run my CURL command.

```
$ curl http://URL/update.json --connect-timeout 10000 --max-time 10000 --data-binary @bars.json -H 'Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8;X-Vendor-Email=myemaiL@gmail.com;'
{"uploaded":true,"message":"Bars JSON received.  A email will be sent after processing has completed."}
```

as you can see, that works fine and uploaded fine to the remote server.  I'm trying to automate this profess by putting this into script file.

my script file:

```
cd /cygdrive/x
curl http://URL/update.json --connect-timeout 10000 --max-time 10000 --data-binary @bars.json -H 'Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8;X-Vendor-Email=EMAIL@gmail.com;
```

error:

```
$ /bin/test.sh
: No such file or directorycygdrive/x
/bin/test.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/test.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a closing `'` to the end of the command.

```sh
curl http://URL/update.json --connect-timeout 10000 --max-time 10000 \
 --data-binary @bars.json \
 -H 'Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8;X-Vendor-Email=EMAIL@gmail.com'
```

Comment: sorry i don't quit follow your suggestion. I should have my first line as ... cd /cygdrive/x'  ? and .... vendor-email=email@gmail.com''   ???

Comment: It's the argument you're passing to the `-H` option. It has a single-quote character to open it (`'Content-type...`) but you're missing the closing one at the end.

Comment: For posterity, I hit this same issue when I was passing user-input from a Ruby script as a string of arguments to a bash script, specifically a username and password.  It so happened that the password I was sending contained a single apostrophe `'`.  In this case the solution was to quote the user input before sending it to the bash script.